# how can I define strings in resource file and use them in qml

Tags: qml

I want to define a number of xml formatted strings in resource file and use the strings in qml code. Is it possible? How to do it? I would be really appreciated any example.

Answer (score 1):

As I know there is no way to store strings in resource file. But you still do that in another way.

**First way:** create language file with qt translation tool. As bonus you can store string in several languages.
Using in QML is very easy:

```
Text {
    text: qsTr("myTextId");
}
```

See [that link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-internationalization.html) for more info.

**Second way:** store each string in different resource file.
But in this case you need to extend QML with C++ plugin to get ability to read files.
See [that link](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Reading_and_writing_files_in_QML) for more info.